# I need to motorway map of the UK as data in CSV format

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

I need the motorway map of the United Kingdom as data in CSV file format.

Comment: If you got it in GML or shapefiles could you convert it to CSV?

Comment: Please, could you give me it and I will try to convert it to CSV

Comment: It will be good if it is as shapefiles

Answer (score 2):

You can get UK road data (including motorways) from the Ordnance Survey (OS) of Great Britain, as part of the OS Open Roads data set.

You can see metadata for the product on the data.gov.uk metadata portal https://data.gov.uk/dataset/os-open-road.

Or go directly to the OS: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-roads.html

Data is available as GML or shapefiles.